# The Role Variational Free Energy or Expected Lower Bound (ELBO) Plays as a Loss Function

Tags: expected-value, kullback-leibler, variational-bayes

In reference to variational free energy or expected lower bound,

[image]

I found this sentence,
"As one can easily see, the cost function tries to balance the complexity of the data P(D | w) and the simplicity of the prior P(w)." mentioned in [this article](https://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter18_variational-methods-and-uncertainty/bayes-by-backprop.html).
I have not been able to clearly make sense of this sentence. I understand that they are referring to a tradeoff here but could someone maybe explain in a more theoretical and mathematical way? I think that way it'll be easier to digest this sentence hence understand the role that this cost function wants to play in a more intuitive way.